# how I can add placeholder and readOnly in ckeditor4-react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ckeditor, ckeditor4.x

Im using `ckeditor4-react` [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ckeditor4-react) in my project and want to add placeholder and want to make it `readOnly` or `disabled` .
How I do this

here is my code

```
 import React from 'react';
 import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';

const Editor= (props) => {

return (
<div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
  <CKEditor
    onBlur={(value) => input.onBlur()}
    data={input.value}
    onChange={event=> input.onChange(event.editor.getData())}
    config={{
      //editorplaceholder: "hello ...", // tried this 
      readOnly:true, // tried this 
      
      //placeholder: "Placeholder text...", // also tried this 
      toolbar: [ [ 'Bold', 'Italic', 'Undo', 'Redo', 'Link', 'Unlink', "NumberedList", "BulletedList","Placeholder" ] ]
      
    }}
 }
   />
 
</div>
 );
}
```

placeholder not working this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

readonly is not an attribute in the config , it should be a separate prop.
and regarding the placeholder you need to adapt the config to be like the following example.
I already tried it and everything worked fine.

```
<div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
  <CKEditor
    config={{
      extraPlugins: "editorplaceholder",
      editorplaceholder: "Start typing here...",
    }}
    readOnly
  />
</div>
```

Comment: how I can set place holder here @Muhammed Said what is `editorplaceholder` here

Comment: you can use like any other object for example create another object outside the return statement and inject it inside the config to be like that 
const customConfig = {extraPlugins: "editorplaceholder", editorplaceholder: "Start typing here..."}

and inside the return in the CKEditor , you can use it  like that 
<CKEditor config={customConfig} >

Comment: and then you can deal with it like any other object , you can set for whatever you would like too. but not that the extraPlugins attribute is not optional in case you would like to use placeholder

Comment: @Asad editorplaceholder is representing the place holder and the value for this attribute will be displayed as placeholder for the ckeditor

Comment: I didnt get you @Mohammed Said can you please help me in doing this with code example

Comment: which extraPlugins I need here and how i can use that

Comment: Just copy the previous code in your component and it will work. I already showed you the correct configuration to add the place holder , all you need to change the value of editorplaceholder attribute to meet your needs. 
you have to leave this attribute       extraPlugins: "editorplaceholder",
as the example I shared

Comment: It dont work if i give the same solution you provided @Muhammed Said

Comment: Here is a link for the solution on sand box
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-aryabhata-6wgiu?file=/src/App.js

Comment: `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {$$typeof, type, key, ref, props, _owner, _store}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: I don't know why, but try this link again https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-halgwb?embed=1&file=src/App.js

Comment: you have used `"ckeditor4-react": "1.4.2"` but mine is `"ckeditor4-react": "^1.1.0"` that might be issue ? @Mohammed

Comment: Ive upgraded my version working now thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make it more clearer,and again readonly is not a configuration attribute. It's a component prop. and the you have to use the config as the example to let the placeHolder work. and the value of editorplaceholder attribute is representing the place holder that will appear in the ckeditor. I hope now every thing is clear

```js
 import React from 'react';
 import CKEditor from 'ckeditor4-react';
 const config = {
      extraPlugins: "editorplaceholder", // it's mandatory to be able to use the place holder
      editorplaceholder: "Write here what ever you would like to show in the place holder", //   this can be what ever you need
}
const Editor= (props) => {

return (
<div className="flex flex-col flex-1">
  <CKEditor
    config={config}
    readOnly={true}
  />
</div>

);
}
```

Comment: its not working it dont show up the editor :(

Comment: can you check it on some anydesk or something ?